# how to keep the checkbox checked and disabled once it is submitted through form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Im my form, i have a list of checkboxes,here i want to show the checked check boxes and disable if it is checked and submitted once.

this is my code,

```
@if(!empty($sublaws))
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li class="law_{{ $law->id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="law_type_id[]" id="law_type_id{{ $law->id }}" class="delclass" value="{{ $law->id }}" reldeltype="{{ $law->id }}" />
        <strong>{{ $law->lm_id }} ( {{ $law->law_name }} )</strong>
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            @foreach ($sublaws as $sublaw)
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="law_sub_type_id[]" id="law_sub_type_id{{$sublaw->id}}" value="{{$sublaw->id}}" class="delsubclass" reldeltype="{{ $law->id }}" reldelsubtype="{{$sublaw->id}}" />
                    {{ $sublaw->lms_id }} ( {{ $sublaw->sub_law_name }} )</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: What do you mean by submitted once ? Is the page remain same after submitting ?

Comment: u can check checkbox by using  input checkbox attribute  `checked="checked"`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes my form remains same with list of checkboxes

Comment: You might be submitting the form using ajax ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes

Comment: But if you have checked 4 checkboxes and you submitted them with ajax, without refresh the page, they will remain checked. I can not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#IdofYourCheckbox").prop('checked', true);
```